# Unable to upload file to datatable and display on the gridview(Nothing happens when i upload files)

Tags: vb.net, gridview, byte

I wanted to add files uploaded to datatable then show it on gridview.When i upload files, nothing happens and gridview is not updated too.I have the code that uploads the file to sql database but now i only want to upload the files to a datatable and show it on the gridview then later the end user can decide whether to insert the files into the sql server database. I am not really sure why i am unable to upload the files, i also tried displaying the variables that i am trying to insert into the datable on a label but nothing happens too. It would be nice if someone could help me with this.

Frontend code

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload" OnClick="Upload" />
<hr />
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#3AC0F2" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"
    RowStyle-BackColor="#A1DCF2" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="White" AlternatingRowStyle-ForeColor="#000"
    AutoGenerateColumns="false" Height="338px" Width="449px">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="filename" HeaderText="File Name"/>
        
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
            
        </div>
    </form>
```

Backend

```
Private dt As DataTable

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not IsPostBack Then
            'BindGrid()

            fill()
            Session("table") = dt
        Else
            ' this is a page post back - re-load the active table into our
            ' forms level dt. 
            dt = Session("table")
            
        End If
    End Sub

 Protected Sub fill()
        dt = New DataTable()
        Dim dc As DataColumn = New DataColumn("file")
        dc.DataType = System.Type.[GetType]("System.Byte[]")
        dt.Columns.Add(dc)
        dt.Columns.Add("filename", GetType(String))
        dt.Columns.Add("filetype", GetType(String))
    End Sub

Protected Sub Upload(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpload.Click
        Dim filename As String = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName)
        Dim contentType As String = FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType
        Dim fs As Stream = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream
        Dim br As New BinaryReader(fs)
        Dim bytes As Byte() = br.ReadBytes(DirectCast(fs.Length, Long))
        Dim R As DataRow = dt.NewRow()
        R("file") = bytes
        R("filename") = filename
        R("filetype") = contentType
        dt.Rows.Add(R)
        GridView1.DataSource = dt
        GridView1.DataBind()
        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri)
        Label1.Text = contentType

    End Sub
```

Comment: A DataTable doesn't have a DataType property.

Comment: You don't have a field in your DataTable called file.

Comment: @Mary i just edited my post with the correct code, copied wrong code. I do have it but still does not work.

Comment: Much better. It seems that ReadBytes is expecting an Integer representing the number of bytes to read and you are passing a Long. Have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.binaryreader.readbytes?view=net-5.0

Comment: @Mary The code still works with readbytes(...,Long), it seems like the problem is Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri), my gridview started displaying something after i remove that line.

Comment: @Mary Thanks alot for the help!, i got everything working properly now. Been stuck on this for quite sometime and i just left it be since its not really essential.